# Track a spot on a turning circle

Tags: image-processing, trigonometry, tracking

I had a question about tracking a spot on a turning circle. As you see in the image I am trying to calculate the *x2* and only known parameters are *θ1*, *L* and *x1*. The challenge is to track that spot on each turn of circle which each step size is *θ1*.

The calculation which gives approximately correct answer is:

x2 = x1 - (L/2 - L/2 * cos(θ1))

[Spot Tracking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4aef.png)

The problem is as the circle turns *x1* deviates more from the correct answer. Is there anyway to calculate *θ2* as circle turns?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The spot motion is described by

```
X = Xc + r cos Θ
Y = Yc + r sin Θ
```

Hence the angle seen from the origin,

```
φ = arctan((Yc + r sin Θ)/(Xc + r cos Θ)).
```

Notice that your problem is indeterminate, as the center of the circle is free to move at distance L of the origin, giving different intersections with the vertical at x1.